# Luma product image height

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, luma-theme

The issue is no matter what **height my product image** is, the page is creating blank buffer space below image.

Here's my code in chrome tools:

**(full size)**
    inherited from div.fotorama__stage
    Style Attribute {
        width: 719px;
        height: 719px;
        line-height: 719px;
    }

**(mobile size)**
inherited from div.fotorama__stage
Style Attribute {
    width: 493px;
    height: 493px;
    line-height: 493px;

Removing the height and line-height in Chrome tools solves my problem. I've removed every height reference in all files containing **fotorama__stage** but nothing works. Does someone know where these attributes are being generated?

Do I need to recompile to make .less files work? I'm a little concerned about doing this because the last time it crashed my whole site.

**Magento V 2.0.13 Luma child theme**

Answer (score 0):

Please check vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\etc\view.xml file

where mention all image size

700
                560

Comment: ok, did that. removed all heights from the 3 tags in my luma and child theme files. no change. What do i need do with these files?

Comment: if you remove then it will take from parent theme so size manage from that.

Comment: ok, but i removed the lines and I'm still seeing 719px height. Where is this coming from? I've done a database search as well.

Comment: it is from parent theme and have you refresh cache and all

Comment: I've removed the 560 height from my child theme, Luma and blank. Refreshed cache. The image area still adjusts at a height of 719px. Ack!